# Combining data in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Dears,

I have 4 columns in excel.

Each row have two values but also it is mapped to another row.

I'd like to sum the values from these the rows that are mapped and delete the extra rows.

Example attached: [Row A has two values but also mapped to Row C. I want to add the values in Row A with the ones in Row C and keep Row A and delete Row C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPhRP.gif)

Is it possible to use formulas instead of VBA as I don't have experience in VBA?

Please advise.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: J2: `{=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF((COUNTIF(J$1:J1,$D$2:$D$6)+COUNTIF(J$1:J1,$A$2:$A$6))=0,ROW($A$2:$A$6)),1)),"")}` / K2: `=IF(J2="","",SUMIF(A:A,J2,B:B)+SUMIF(D:D,J2,B:B))` / L2: `=IF(J2="","",SUMIF(A:A,J2,C:C)+SUMIF(D:D,J2,C:C))` and copy down... just extend the ranges for column A and D in the first formula to match your criteria... also the first formula is an array-formula and must be confirmed with ctrl+shift+enter (the {} will show up automatically / you do not type them in manually)

Comment: Didn't work. I pasted the formula in Column E and dragged for Rows A->E, but the formula is not executed. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your Keyword data starts with A2 and Value 1 starts with B2 and Value 2 starts with C2. (Please refer the snap below)

Apply the below formula in H2 for Value 1 summing and drag down

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$D$4,4,FALSE)=0,VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$D$4,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$D$4,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$D$4,4,FALSE),$A$2:$D$4,2,FALSE))
```

Apply the below formula in I2 for Value 2 summing and drag down

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$D$4,4,FALSE)=0,VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$D$4,3,FALSE),VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$D$4,3,FALSE)+VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$D$4,4,FALSE),$A$2:$D$4,3,FALSE))
```

[image]

**EDIT #1** If G value does not contain in Table 1 then apply the below formula

in H2

```
=IF(ISERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$D$4,4,FALSE)=0,VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$D$4,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$D$4,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$D$4,4,FALSE),$A$2:$D$4,2,FALSE))),"Not Found in Table",IF(VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$D$4,4,FALSE)=0,VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$D$4,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$D$4,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$D$4,4,FALSE),$A$2:$D$4,2,FALSE)))
```

in I2

```
=IF(ISERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$D$4,4,FALSE)=0,VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$D$4,3,FALSE),VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$D$4,3,FALSE)+VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$D$4,4,FALSE),$A$2:$D$4,3,FALSE))),"Not Found in Table",IF(VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$D$4,4,FALSE)=0,VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$D$4,3,FALSE),VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$D$4,3,FALSE)+VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$D$4,4,FALSE),$A$2:$D$4,3,FALSE)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but C shouldn't appear.

Comment: Edit #1: C should have have mapping to A. You can't delete it. Is it possible to make the values of C to be 0 because it's values are already added to A? This way I can filter all rows that value1 and value 2 = 0 and then delete them.

Comment: if you want to delete the mapped content, its possible in VBA